# Recover Jar from Running Application

Tags: java, linux, bash, maven, jar

Context: I have a Maven application running, but have deleted the directory it is running in along with all of the code.

Question: Is it possible to find the running .jar somewhere? I know if I do, I can run it through a decompiler and get my code back.

Edit: More context. I ran the application. Then while the application was running the entire directory was deleted. The command to run was  ./mvnw spring-boot:run, so I cannot find the package in the maven repository.

Comment: You're running a deleted jar file?

Comment: ps -ef showing anything?

Comment: if you build the application with `mvn install`, you may retrieve the jar in your maven local repository.

Comment: @bobdylan I know the process number, I don't know how to connect that to where I can find the jar in memory.

Comment: @davidxxx How would I find it in the local repository?

Comment: Usually look in your user directory under `.m2/repository`

Comment: @JFMeier The package is com.starter.messages but the directory ~/.m2/com/starter doesn't exist.

Comment: The directory must be `.m2/repository/com/starter`. At least if you did not change the local repository location e.g. in the settings.xml.

Comment: @JFMeier My mistake. I checked that directory and it doesn't exist.

Comment: Then you probably never ran `mvn install`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about jar file. However, individual classes of running application are recoverable.

I reckon few options.

You can dump entire process memory and use tools to analyze it's content.

You also can write a Java Agent to extract classes from the running JVM instance.

Or you can use tools like https://github.com/frontfact/jvminspector to browse loaded classes and save them manually.

Once you've recovered classes assembling them into a jar is trivial.

See also: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14675/extracting-classes-from-running-jvm